# Не получаеться конвертация из .ui в .py с помощью команды pyqt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

На pyuic5 gui.ui -o gui.py пишет ошибку в терминале

```
pyuic5 : Имя "pyuic5" не распознано как имя командлета, функции, файла сценария или выполняемой программы. Проверьте правильность написания имени, а также наличие и правильность пути, после чего повторите попытку.
строка:1 знак:1
+ pyuic5 gui.ui -o gui.py
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pyuic5:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

А в консоли пайтон

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\code.py", line 63, in runsource
    code = self.compile(source, filename, symbol)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\codeop.py", line 153, in __call__
    return _maybe_compile(self.compiler, source, filename, symbol)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\codeop.py", line 70, in _maybe_compile
    compiler(source + "\n", filename, symbol)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\codeop.py", line 118, in __call__
    codeob = compile(source, filename, symbol, self.flags, True)
  File "<input>", line 1
    pyuic5 gui.ui -o gui.py
           ^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: в первом примере вам явно дают понять, что вы не установили `pyuic` (`pip install pyqt5-tools`)

Comment: а так  `python -m PyQt5.uic.pyuic -x uiname.ui -o pyname.py` ?

Comment: @n1tr0xs у меня он не устанавливаеться pyqt5-tools, я скачал puqt5-Designer

Comment: @S.Nick спасибо

Comment: Гриша Хохлова  получилось ?

Comment: @S.Nick, Да у меня получилось

Comment: Гриша Хохлова удачи вам.

Comment: @S.Nick спасибо